# prolog arguments are not sufficently instantiated

Tags: if-statement, prolog, instantiation-error

I am trying to find max,mid and min number from 3 given number. The code is:

```
t_max(X,Y,Z):-
    A is max(max(X,Y),max(Y,Z)),
    C is min(min(X,Y),min(Y,Z)),
    (X>=A,X=<C)->B is X;
    (Y>=A,Y=<C)->B is Y;
    (Z>=A,Z=<C)->B is Z;
    format('~w      ~w      ~w',[A,B,C]).
```

When i try to run  the method with any three numbers, I get this error

```
ERROR: >=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Can you give a sample call?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , a sample call would be t_max(3, 5, 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `;` binds with lower priority than the `,` so what you have written is equivalent to:

```
t_max(X, Y, Z) :-
    (   A is max(max(X, Y), max(Y, Z)),
        C is min(min(X, Y), min(Y, Z)),
        X>=A,
        X=<C
    ->  B is X
    ;   Y>=A,
        Y=<C
    ->  B is Y
    ;   Z>=A,
        Z=<C
    ->  B is Z
    ;   format('~w      ~w      ~w', [A, B, C])
    ).
```

What does this mean: Prolog evaluates:

```
A is max(max(X,Y),max(Y,Z)),
C is min(min(X,Y),min(Y,Z)),
```

first and then checks the condition:

```
X>=A,X=<C
```

if that fails however, **the program backtracks entirely to the beginning of the clause**. So now `A` and `C` are again uninstantiated and Prolog performs a new attempt by checking:

```
Y>=A,Y=<C
```

but now `A` and `C` are not grounded.

You can resolve the problem by adding brackets:

```
t_max(X,Y,Z):-
    A is max(max(X,Y),max(Y,Z)),
    C is min(min(X,Y),min(Y,Z)),
    ((X>=C,X=<A)
     -> B is X
     ; ((Y>=C,Y=<A)
        ->B is Y
        ; ((Z>=C,Z=<A)
           -> B is Z;
           true
          )
       )
    ),
    format('~w      ~w      ~w',[A,B,C]).
```

If I understand your problem correctly. If you however want to sort them from large to small, a compact way to do this for three numbers is:

```
t_max(X,Y,Z) :-
    Max is max(X,max(Y,Z)),
    Min is min(X,min(Y,Z)),
    Mid is X+Y+Z-Max-Min,
    format('~w      ~w      ~w',[Max,Mid,Min]).
```

Comment: I think you may have missed some parenthesis because it is showing compile error at line 12 with message "expected operator". Can you check it?

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib: you were right. Does it work now?

Comment: sorry to bother you but now it is showing garbage value of 'B' variable for the call t_max(3, 5, 7). the output is: "7      _G368      3".

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib: but that is because all three conditions fail.

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib: not that `A` is the maximum and `C` is the minimum, so all conditions will **always** fail. You probably want to swap `A` and `C`?

Comment: Please accept my apology for this silly mistake. I swapped them. But after swapping it is showing same value for 'B' and 'C' variable for the call "t_max(3,5,7)." [output:"7      3      3"]. But if i change the order of these numbers like"t_max(5,3,7).", then I get the right output like "7      5      3".

Comment: Thanks for your help. finally it working for all sort of numbers. The equal checks were making troubles.

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib: I've added a predicate that definitely is more compact and thus less error prone (and probably faster).

Comment: its perfect. I wish that i would have thought of that way in the beginning.